# Ensure Base Chains Exist for Nftables and Set nftables configuration for loopback traffic

Tags: networking

I have disabled ufw and enabled nftables but `usg audit cis_level1_server` is persistently flagging `Ensure Base Chains Exist for Nftables` and `Set nftables configuration for loopback traffic`.

My `/etc/nftables.conf` is below.

A similar question was [asked on /r/Ubuntu](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/14skoj6/ubuntu_2204_cis_level_1_workstation_benchmark/).

I would particularly like to see a pointer to **any** `/etc/nftables.conf` that passes `usg audit cis_level1_server`.

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table inet filter {

    chain inbound_ipv4 {
    }

    chain inbound_ipv6 {
        icmpv6 type { nd-neighbor-solicit, nd-router-advert, nd-neighbor-advert } accept
    }

    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;

        ct state vmap { established : accept, related : accept, invalid : drop }

        iif "lo" accept
        ip  saddr 127.0.0.0/8 counter drop
        ip6 saddr ::1         counter drop

        meta protocol vmap { ip : jump inbound_ipv4, ip6 : jump inbound_ipv6 }

        tcp dport { 22 } accept
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        ip protocol tcp ct state established,related,new accept
        ip protocol udp ct state established,related,new accept
        ip protocol icmp ct state established,related,new accept
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when trying to configure Server_Level_2. I took a look at the benchmark documentation, and found that the following was being used as the audit command

nft list ruleset | awk '/hook input/,/}/' | iif "lo" accept

My issue was, that I had a comma in my configuration from ct state { established, related } ... which cut the awk pipe early, before it reached my loopback config. Moving these above the config with a comma resulted in a pass.

It looks like you may have the same issue, where your " ct state vmap { established : accept, related : accept, invalid : drop }" ends the awk output earlier than the benchmark intended.

Try applying this config (semantically the same, but should pass loopback benchmark):

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table inet filter {

    chain inbound_ipv4 {
    }

    chain inbound_ipv6 {
        icmpv6 type { nd-neighbor-solicit, nd-router-advert, nd-neighbor-advert } accept
    }

    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
        
        iif "lo" accept
        ip  saddr 127.0.0.0/8 counter drop
        ip6 saddr ::1         counter drop
        
        ct state vmap { established : accept, related : accept, invalid : drop }

        

        meta protocol vmap { ip : jump inbound_ipv4, ip6 : jump inbound_ipv6 }

        tcp dport { 22 } accept
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        ip protocol tcp ct state established,related,new accept
        ip protocol udp ct state established,related,new accept
        ip protocol icmp ct state established,related,new accept
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
    }
}
```